# jquery change attribute of a DOM element inside more divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Let say I have to change the action of a form inside several divs:

```
<div class="div1" id="contact">
            <div class="div2">
               <div class="div3">
                <form class="contactform" action="" method="post">
                    <button type="submit"></button>
                </form>
               </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

How do I change the `action` attribute of the `form` with `class="contact form"` using jQuery ?

Comment: `$('.div1').find('form.contactform').attr('action','youraction')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have only on form in the page then you can change the attributes directly with all the css selector like:

```
$('form').attr('action', 'theupdatedaction');
```

where `$('form')` is the tag name selector which selects all the `form`s available on the page. This can be changed to `#`id selectors and `.` class selector:

```
 $('.contactform') // for class selector
 $('#contactform') // for ID selector
```

Even you can use `.find()` from the parent element:

```
$('#contact').find('.contactform').attr('action', 'theupdatedaction');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 $(".contactform").attr("action", "newaction");
```